# Print accented letters and emoticons

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, printing, stream

I also want to print emoticons when I’m on a live broadcast and I’m writing messages, unfortunately it prints code marks instead of accents and emoticons, could someone help, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: I program in Python, I am a very beginner, I am learning.  you have already added the script and with accents and emoticons unfortunately it does not print normally

Comment: Please click [edit] then paste example code so we have a [mcve]

Comment: We do not know what you mean by "live broadcast" Is this discord or what?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.